# Laravel new Sessions on every refresh and 419 when submit login form

Tags: laravel, session, server

I'm working on laravel project which is working correctly in localhost but when I deploy on a subdomain on my server it is facing issues with sessions. I'm using session driver file. When I login, it says 419 your session has expired. It creates a new session file in storage/framework/sessions whenever I refresh that login page. But locally it creates only 1session file browser and log me in and do not show 419. Moreover cookie exist for localhost link in browser but did not created of my domain.

Please help

Comment: Can't speak to the subdomain issue, but I had this happen recently for a load balancer, and the solution was the use `SESSION_DRIVER=database` so the session storage location was centrally accessible. This _might_ work for you, see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#driver-prerequisites for full details, but I'm not sure about `file` approach.

Comment: You need to clear config from your live server, then it will work fine `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I have tried php artisan config:clear ,cache:clear ,route:clear , config:cache,key:generate but no success

Comment: Do you have `session.lifetime` set in your config?

Comment: Yes it is set to 120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN my case, issue was a space before PHP starting tag in routes/api.php

It can also due to space before an PHP starting tag in routes/* files or config/* files

and it can also due to if any of these files have PHP closing tag